# Cannot start any django app

Tags: django

I am a newbie at Django and everytime I try to run 
`python panel/manage.py startapp %app%` (panel is my project) it gives me the error:

```
Error: '%app%' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Surely companies or contacts or stats is not the name of an existing Python module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you need to

```
cd panel
python manage.py startapp yourappname
```

I'm not sure running the command from a directory above your project will work properly.

Comment: Maybe something like this can be in Linux, but authors error tells us, that Django tried to create application, but it has conflict with Python module.

Comment: But the error message seems incorrect, so I'm guessing at something else that looks odd.

Comment: Any directory in the Python path (which includes the current directory) that has an `__init__.py` file in it is considered a module.

Comment: Any application is giving me this error even if I am in the folder.

Comment: You know what guys I am so sorry I got confused thinking it reloads the instance of the app instead of creating it.

Comment: This should not be the selected answer. CDing into the directory has nothing to do with conflicting with python packages.

Answer (score 28):

This is a fun one - your **project** and your **app** need to have different names.  You probably created a project, then tried to startapp with the same name.

Comment: There must be a reason for this. Why?

Answer (score 17):

I was confused as well, until I realized that a Django project is a container for applications; this sequence makes it a bit clearer:

```
# first create a Project (container).
django-admin.py startproject Project

# create multiple apps
cd Project
python manage.py startapp polls
python manage.py startapp hello
...
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue as a Django newbie because I was trying to "restart" my app after carrying out changes, but `startapp` is meant to be used once ***to create a new app***.

To view changes, syncronize app with DB with `python manage.py migrate` and restart the server with `python manage.py runserver` instead.

From the `django-admin` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#startapp-app-label-destination)

([`manage.py` does essentially the same thing as `django-admin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#))

> **`startapp <app_label> [destination]`**
>
> **django-admin startapp**
>
> Creates a Django app directory structure for
> the given app name in the current directory or the given destination.
>
> By default the directory created contains a models.py file and other
> app template files. (See the source for more details.) If only the app
> name is given, the app directory will be created in the current
> working directory.
>
> If the optional destination is provided, Django will use that existing
> directory rather than creating a new one. You can use ‘.’ to denote
> the current working directory.
>
> For example:
>
> **`django-admin startapp myapp /Users/jezdez/Code/myapp`**

Answer (score 5):

I reproduced the issue and there's actually something not working as I expected.
I wonder if we stumbled upon a Django's bug, or a limitation that I don't understand.

Having a project called "project" and an empty folder app/newapp
…I tried:

```
python manage.py startapp newapp apps/newapp
```

It returns:

```
CommandError: 'newapp' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

But if I target ANY other route in which the last folder is not called the same name as the app I'm starting, it works.

So I ended up doing:

```
python manage.py startapp newapp apps/main
```

Using Django 2.1.3.

Comment: This is the reason for the error, unless app name is the same as project name. This should be the accepted answer as OP said all app names return the error. It was because the app was being placed in a folder with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

This message is displayed if you run "startapp" twice with the same app name.  As pointed out above by the OP it doesn't reload the app, it creates one.

Comment: So how do you fix it? I created the app in the wrong directory first time around.

Comment: No. I'm getting this message at the project level, not the app level.

Answer (score 3):

You should choose different names for your project and app in Codes:

```
django-admin startproject **my_project** 

python manage.py startapp **my_app**
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the directory before using the commands. Suppose you want a polls app inside apps folder.

```sh
mkdir apps apps/polls
python manage.py startapp polls apps/polls
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess maybe you have already created the app's dir in panel dir manually. The command 'startapp' is to create an app automatically. If you already have one there, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make an empty directory that will contain your new app

```
project-dir
    └── blog
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
        ├── blog-ext #this empty dir that will contain the new app
        └── views.py
```

so instead of typing :

```
python manage.py newapp blog/blog-ext
```

it should be :

```
django-admin startapp newapp blog/blog-ext
```

Answer (score 1):

Try classic "mysite" or "myproject". You can delete it anytime you want, so if it will accepted, then all your privious ideas conflict with Python modules.

Edit: I tried all your ideas, there was no error for me. So, if you installed support libraries or modules for django, then some of them can contains such names.

Answer (score 1):

this error is because of the name conflicts between the app name and project name.you had given same name for your app and project .your project and app need to be different name .if you had given the same name the above mentioned error will occur .

**understand the difference between  app and  project**

Projects vs. apps

What’s the difference between a project and an app? An app is a Web application that does something – e.g., a Weblog system, a database of public records or a simple poll app. A project is a collection of configuration and apps for a particular Web site. A project can contain multiple apps. An app can be in multiple projects.

**first create the project.**
**then create the app.**

**NOTE: name for app and project should be different**

## first create a project with projectname

```
 django-admin.py startproject Projectname .
```

## Then create app with appname. (to create your app make sure you are in the same  directory manage.py and type this command)

```
python manage.py  startapp Appname
```

Comment: No. I'm getting this error where the app name is completely separate from the project name.

Answer (score 1):

It's the process how I got my doubt clear.

First, I created a directory inside my project directory and put __init__.py, models.py, admin.py, apps.py & views.py.

Then I ran **python manage.py runserver** & It work well.

Then as suggested on that page I used startapp command. I got this error :

```
CommandError: 'ucportal' conflicts with the name of an existing Python 
module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

After that I deleted that directory and ran startapp command with same name and it worked fine.

So 'startapp' command  is to create an app automatically. If you already have one there, it fails.

Answer given by @DAG worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to set up a Wagtail project.

Before creating the app, I had created and activated a virtualenv (using virtualenvwrapper) with the same name: $APPNAME. When I then ran `wagtail start $APPNAME`, Django looks for naming conflics in the $PYTHONPATH which in this instance points to /Users/User/.virtualenvs.

Naturally, this results in a conflict as /Users/User/.virtualenvs/$APPNAME already exists.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers helped me. In the end I ended up creating an app with a different name and then just renaming the directory to the app name I wanted all along. Note that you also will need to change the class name in apps.py to match your app name.

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply Use This command

for Django Project Creation

```
python -m django startproject name_of_django_Project
```

for Django App Creation

```
python -m django  startapp App_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when working with wagtail cms. I got this error even there is no such a created app. This occurs when there is an app already that has the same name you need to create inside the **site-packages directory**.

Once you get this error, you need to check the following directory,

**C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages**

If there is a package with the name same you want to create then you need to remove that package. **Also make sure to check that package is important or not before deleting**.

Answer (score 0):

The application directory should be created first.

Example: apps/practice

The command appears to be duplicated, but it is correct.

Example: python manage.py startapp practice ./apps1/practice