# Cannot start django app

Tags: python, django, web, frameworks, development-environment

I am a newbie at Django and everytime I try to run   `(myvenv) C:\Users\lenovo> python manage.py startapp blog`it gives me the error:

```
CommandError: 'blog' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start any django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019070/cannot-start-any-django-app)

Answer (score 3):

You can't run the command from a directory above your project.
you should do this:

```
cd projectName
python manage.py startapp blog
```