# Django app conflicts with an existing Python module

Tags: django, bash

I have a function that generates a bash script file '.sh' to create a django project and a few apps.

This is the bash file I generate:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd projectx
source projectxenv/Scripts/activate
python manage.py startapp app1
python manage.py startapp app2
deactivate
```

When I execute the bash I generated, it gives me the following errors:

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: 'app1' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.

django.core.management.base.CommandError: 'app2' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

I don't think app1 and app2 are existing modules, and also, I tried running these commands manually and they work, but when I try `./bash.sh`, it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019070/cannot-start-any-django-app/18932847

Comment: Actually I saw it already, it doesn't help at all. I'm well aware of the commands I'm using, and also as I said, I tried these commands manually in shell command and they work, they only don't work when executed as part of a bash file.

Comment: Maybe try changing the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: I'll change it to `#! /"""+directory+"env/"+"""/bin/env bash` and see (because it's a generated bash file on django)

Comment: Using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` should be sufficient to get the same results you see when running commands in your shell. `/usr/bin/env` is what you want -- it's not going to exist anywhere else.

Comment: For reference: [What is the difference between "#!/usr/bin/env bash" and "#!/usr/bin/bash"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16365130/5747944)